# tf.cast not changing the dtype ORIGINAL ISSUE:tensorflowjs Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'conv2d' must be float32 tensor, but got int32 tensor

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to load a model I develop in tensorflow (Python) with tensorflowjs and make  prediction for an input test, as follow:

```
tf_model = await tf.loadGraphModel('http://localhost:8080/tf_models/models_js/model/model.json')
let test_output = await tf_model.predict(tf.tensor2d([0.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1, 9], 'float32'))
console.log("[Test tf model]:", test_output.arraySync())
```

I'm getting this error in the js console at tf_model.predict

```
Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'conv2d' must be float32 tensor, but got int32 tensor
```

even if the input of the Conv2D Layer is of type float32 in the model definition

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((9))

# One-Hot encoding
x = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(tf.cast(inputs + 1, tf.int32), 3), tf.float32)

x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 3, 3, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=3**5, kernel_size=(3, 3), kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
    )(x)
```

Anybody knows why this could happen?

EDIT:
It seems tf.cast does not change the type, if I run

```
print(tf.shape(inputs))
x = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(tf.cast(inputs + 1, tf.int32), 3), tf.float32)
print(tf.shape(x)
```

I keep getting tf.int32

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), inferred_value=[None, 9], name='tf.compat.v1.shape_12/Shape:0', description="created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.shape_12'")
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), inferred_value=[None, 9, 3], name='tf.compat.v1.shape_13/Shape:0', description="created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.shape_13'")
```

???

Comment: What's the output of `tf.shape(x)`, or `x.dtype`

Comment: (None,9) -> OneHot -> (None, 9, 3) -> Reshape -> (None, 3,3,3) -> Conv2D -> (None, 1, 1, 729). In python the model works without issues, I get the error only running it in tfjs

Comment: ok thanks I see the issue it is still a int32, but I don't understand why

Comment: You can convert int32 to float. Try `tf.cast(x, np.float32)` or maybe `tf.cast(x, "float32")`

Comment: See if your tensor is float32 before calling `tf.one_hot()` (and also if you changed the dtype to float instead of int)

Comment: it's always int32 even if I cast it or change the type in the Input ... I tried also the numpy dtypes and the strings, but same result

Comment: Are you using tf 1.0?

Comment: no i'm on the version 2.7.0

Comment: I also opened a new question that's a follow-up of the same issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431128/tf-cast-not-changing-the-dtype-original-issuetensorflowjs-error-argument-x-p, the behavior gets weird, like the tensor itself changes dtype but not when calling tf.shape and it looks like tfjs does not recognize the float32 but the int32 ...

Comment: sorry the other question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432613/tf-cast-not-changing-dtype

Comment: Maybe you can multiply the tensor by a float to force the cast? Have you tried `x *= 1.0`

Comment: Yes tried nothing changes, i think there is some misinterpretation of the model in  tfjs or during the saving from tf .. i ll try to investigate the model.json produced by tfjs converter ..

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody gets the same error, the answer I got from the github repository maintainers is that TFJS right now only supports int32 output for onehot op. Anyway they already merged two pull requests to the master branch to probably fix the issue in the next future, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6773
EDIT: now fixed since release 3.20

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).