# tf.cast not changing dtype

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting

I encountered a weird behavior in the function tf.cast Tensorflow 2.7.0, running the following code

```
inputs = tf.constant(np.array([[0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 1.]]),dtype=tf.float32)
print(tf.shape(inputs))

x = tf.cast(inputs + 1, tf.int32)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.one_hot(x, 3)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
print(tf.shape(x))
```

I get

```
tf.Tensor([1 9], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 9], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 9 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 9 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

I cannot find the reason why tf.cast it's not changing the type to float32, but not even the first tensor inputs is a float32 even if I defined it as float32 ...
I already tried also the numpy dtypes with the same result

EDIT: but if I print the tensor it tells me float32

```
tf.Tensor([1 9], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([[ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.]], shape=(1, 9), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1 9], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([[1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 2]], shape=(1, 9), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 9 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]], shape=(1, 9, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1 9 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]], shape=(1, 9, 3), dtype=float32)
```

This is generating a problem when then I save the model and load it into tensorflow.js. The conv2d layer in tensorflow.js does not accept int32 as input, and throws an error, so I'm quite puzzled ...

Comment: `tf.shape(x)` is returning int, the original input will be changed, did you try printing out the tensor after every step?

Comment: if I print it it tells float32, but then I have a problem because when I save the model and loaded it to tensorflow.js It throws an error because the conv2d layer can accept only float32 ... so really not sure what's happening ...

Comment: I edited the question to show you the print of the tensors